# Hibernate Envers как узнать классы/сущности в Revision

Tags: hibernate

Здравствуйте. Если в одной транзакции изменяются несколько сущностей, то у них будет совпадать id ревизии. Поэтому мне надо достать из ревизии все обьекты, что она содержит. Но метод принимает всего 1 класс сущности, и для того, чтобы получить все сущности из ревизии, мне надо получить все классы сущностей, что содержит ревизия.   
Пробовал делать через родительский класс (superClass), но там возникает ошибка.

```
-superClass    
----Class1  
----Class2
```

Вытаскиваю сущности вот таким образом:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

AuditQuery query =  reader.createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(Class1.class,num)
.add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(num));
List<Object> results = query.getResultList();
```

**Обновление**

Заранее неизвестно, какие классы будут в ревизии. Их у меня около 10 штук.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел как. Работать надо с `getCrossTypeRevisionChangesReader()`

[Пример](http://lukaszantoniak.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/hhh-5580/)

[Документация](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges)

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь пригодится.